# Add a button to reset WordPress theme options

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a theme options page for a WordPress theme, and I need to add a **Reset** button to clear all the user defined settings for theme options.

I'm told that this function will do the job,

```
function reset_mytheme_options() { 
    remove_theme_mods();
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'reset_mytheme_options' );
```

But, don't know how to run this function on a button click.

So, will this function do what I needed ? If so, how to run it on a button click ?

Comment: Are you using theme_mods or Settings API for your theme options ?

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned you are using settings API then you can implement in this way.

1. Add button in theme option page after the submit button.

   `submit_button(__('Reset'), 'secondary', 'reset', false);`
2. When you registering settings pass the validation callback

   `register_setting('option_group', 'options_name', 'save_theme_option');`
3. When form is submitted by `reset` button then check the request for reset and return the default settings.

Example

```
function save_theme_option($input) {
    if (isset($_POST['reset'])) {
        add_settings_error('settingName', 'SettingSlug', __('Your settings has been changed defualt setting.', 'text-domain'), 'updated');
        return array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2); //Default settings
    }

    return $input;
}
```